# Fetch json by ID in React from parent component

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have worked in React before, but somehow I can't get it to work, even though it should be something really simple. I have a Child component where I loop through a JSON that contains ID's of products (just in this example), and in every iteration I want to fetch the details. Instead of returning a product object, it returns a response object. I can't figure out what I overlooked. Want to keep it as simple as possible for now, not using axios.

Filename: App.js:

```
fetchProductByID = async (id) => {
    let url = endpoint + id // response is productByID object
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}
```

Filename: Products.js

```
{items.map((data, key) => {
    const productByID = props.fetchProductByID(data.ID)
    return (
        <tr key={key}> 
            <td>{productByID.name}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

**productByID is always a response object and never the productByID object I've fetched.**

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

When I console.log(result) I see the productByID object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the async on your fetchBy method, and awaiting on that method in your map...

```
fetchProductByID = async (id) => {

const productByID = await props.fetchProductByID(data.ID)
```

**update**
This may get you further along...

```
// add await to call async method.
// which means the map function needs to be async
{items.map(async (data, key) => {
    const productByID = await props.fetchProductByID(data.ID)
    return (
        <tr key={key}> 
            <td>{productByID.name}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Comment: Adding await without async in the Child component doesn't work.

Comment: also add it in project.js... const productByID = AWAIT props.fetchProductByID(data.ID)

Comment: I guess you meant products.js, and I did add it there; this is the error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Comment: yes products.js. And if you add await there, you need THAT method to be async too, so also add it to the function that's the map parameter (see updated code). That might do the trick.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work, however I created an async function out of the loop as follows:

const [productByID, setproductByID] = useState({});

const getproductByID = async (id) => {
  const productByID = await props.fetchProductByID(id)
  setproductByID(productByID)
}

Comment: Found this example: https://medium.com/leniolabs/using-async-await-in-react-props-880255a92614